# Xamarin Forms - Is it possible to show part of an html page in WebView?

Tags: html, xamarin.forms, youtube

Is it possible to show part of an html page in WebView?
I need to show only the part that contains the like button in a YouTube video.

Comment: For android you can do this by extending WebViewClient and injecting some javascript which will render your web Page.

Comment: @Leo Zhu, I'm newbie in Xamarin Forms.Would you have an example?